# Define length of array in JSON.stringify in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json

I would like to save the values of form in `JSON` for send $http.post
 there is 1 value `rooms` that should be array and length of this array is depend on value of `md-select` and I should pass value of `Adulat` inside each rooms .

```
var data = {
rooms: [{
    adults: this.adultsHotels,
  }]
```

my view for rooms :

```
<md-select ng-model="rooms" name="numberOfRooms" ng-required="true">
  <md-option ng-repeat="roomsHotel in roomsHotel"
             ng-model="roomsHotel"
             ng-selected = "$first"
             ng-value="roomsHotel.number"
             ng-messages>
            {{roomsHotel.number}}
  </md-option>
</md-select>
```

and controller for room is :

```
$scope.roomsHotel = ('1 2 3 4 5').split(' ').map(function(roomsHotel) {
    return {number: roomsHotel};
  });
```

and adult select view is :

```
<md-select ng-model="adultsHotels" name="numberOfAdults" ng-required="true">
    <md-option ng-repeat="adultsHotel in adultsHotel"
               ng-model="adultsHotel"
               value="{{adultsHotel.number}}"
               ng-messages>
                {{adultsHotel.number}}      
    </md-option>
</md-select>
```

Ps:
the goal is when choose 2 rooms it add 2 room and add adults number in each
any help will highly appreciate

```
 "rooms": [
    {
        "adults": "1"
    },
    {
        "adults": "2"
    }
]
```

Comment: Please share what still you have tried to achieve your goal, some plunkr or fiddle, etc. or try to give more explanations if possible.

Comment: Dear @MayurAgarwal now I canot get more than 1 rooms here is plunkr link
https://plnkr.co/edit/pdgII4EBnekCkVnrkrJj?p=preview
now embedded adult value corectley but I would like when choose 2 rooms adults embedded inside 2 {} as last part of code inside my question
Hope plunkr and explain is Ok with you and help to solve

Comment: check my answer... and let me know for any problem

Comment: Dear @MayurAgarwal thanks for time and answer but with your code push the number of room inside rooms .
my goal is use the number of room as length of rooms as when choose 2 the data is :
    `"rooms": [
        {
            "adults": "1"
        },
        {
            "adults": "2",
        }
      ] `
and mean while there is much for filed that they are not array and regarding to easy to read I didnt mention in question there for I have to asing `var data` inside `$scope.submitHotelsCtrl` hope I'm clear enough to show my issue

Comment: @MayurAgarwal I edit plunkr `https://plnkr.co/edit/pdgII4EBnekCkVnrkrJj?p=preview` already I define rooms lengh but its outside of the `data={}` and I dont know how to bring inside the data, Thanks

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/Zquy6rDFM1iUvNi0FfSF?p=preview this plunker is working as per your requirement... check this once..  this is a rough code.. if this is your requirement, then I will update my answer and explain it.  thanks

Comment: @MayurAgarwal yes this is exactly what I want Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood your code from this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/pdgII4EBnekCkVnrkrJj?p=preview),
you can modify your script file with below code:

```
// Code goes here


var app = angular.module('app', ["ngMaterial"]);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.roomsHotel = ('1 2 3 4 5').split(' ').map(function(roomsHotel) {
    return {number: roomsHotel};
  });
  $scope.adultsHotel = ('1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15').split(' ').map(function(adultsHotel) {
    return {number: adultsHotel};
  });

  $scope.submitHotelsCtrl = function(response){  
    var rooms = [];
    var totalAdults = parseInt(this.adultsHotels);
    var roomsToFill = parseInt(this.rooms);
     var roomsSelected = parseInt(this.rooms);

    var maxPeopleInRoom = Math.ceil(totalAdults/roomsToFill);      
    for(var j=0; j < roomsSelected; j++){

      if(roomsToFill > 1){
        if(totalAdults >= maxPeopleInRoom){
        var peopleToOccupyInRoom = Math.ceil(totalAdults/roomsToFill);
        totalAdults-=peopleToOccupyInRoom;
        rooms.push({'adults': peopleToOccupyInRoom});
        roomsToFill--;
        }else{
          rooms.push({'adults': totalAdults});    
        }
      }else{
        rooms.push({'adults': totalAdults});  
      }
    }

  var data = {'rooms': rooms
},myObjJSON = JSON.stringify(data);
console.log(data);
console.log(rooms);
}
});
```

I know, this code can be improved but meanwhile this should work for you, let me know if issue persists.

New [plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/Zquy6rDFM1iUvNi0FfSF?p=preview)